# Why is name mangling used with the WinMain() function?

Tags: c, winapi, name-mangling

Based on my understanding, name mangling is used when there is function overloading, so that the functions with the same name can be distinguished.

But I have noticed that name mangling is also used with the `WinMain()` function (which is not overloaded). After name mangling it becomes `_WinMain@16`.

So why is name mangling used with the `WinMain()` function?

---

This is the code that I used:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the compiler actually *did* mangle the `WinMain` symbol, it would be something completely different from what you see. What you see is the compiler having *special treatment* of the `WinMain` symbol.

Comment: I believe `_WinMain@16` is some internal name used by the mingw/gcc compiler. What the 16 is supposed to mean, I have no idea.

Comment: @Lundin the `@` means `stdcall` calling convention, the `16` is the size of the parameter list (here: 4 times a 4 bytes argument). Functions using other calling conventions are decorated differently.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ooh, I didn't know that! Actually that means perfect sense. Although, how does the caller know of the return type in that case? Logically, shouldn't it rather be `4_WinMain@16` or `_WinMain@20` or some such? And is this defined by the ABI or by Mingw?

Comment: @Lundin with `cdecl`, you don't need any information on the argument list size at all, and I'm not deep enough into the different calling conventions available on windows, but it seems the linkers only need to know the size of the arguments for `stdcall` ... ;)

Comment: C does not use name mangling.

Comment: @Olaf it does, kind of. Give the same name to several static variables in different scopes and see what will happen.

Comment: That's not name mangling, it's name decoration. Mangling is a C++ concept.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Apparently the cdecl calling convention doesn't allow for any other return types than one register (4 bytes), "register 0". So I suppose that if you try to return a double or some such, the compiler will have to pass part of it through parameters behind the lines.

Comment: @Lundin I'd appreciate a reference to the standard. Note: I did not talk about a specific implementation. About symbols with **internal** linkage: There is no need to do so. That might be a debugging aid, though.

Comment: @Olaf It isn't standardized. But obviously a compiler faced with 50 variables all called `foo` will have to use some manner of name mangling - highly implementation-defined.

Comment: No. The compiler will not allow redefinitions of that kind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), "name mangling" and "name decoration" are two names for the same thing. Do you have any sort of official reference for "name mangling" being a C++-only thing?

Comment: @Olaf if they are in different scopes, it's not a redefinition. And sure, there's no **need** to create symbol names for objects with internal linkage. Compilers still do it.

Comment: @davmac those terms are not defined by a standard, so there's some ambiguity on their usage. Still, what you commonly mean by "name mangling" is what C++ compilers do to create symbol names including all kind of information, so overloaded functions are distinguishable. What's shown here (just adding a little info on the calling convention) is commonly referred to as *decorating*. But you could probably argue a lot on the terms ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Different scopes are resolved by a simple stack-like, resp. hierarchical (for struct/union) symbol table.

Comment: @Olaf I get e.g. `x.1276` and `x.1279` for two `static int x;` defined in different scopes. Compilers could do whatever for naming these symbols.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: That is your implementation the, not a requirement of the language or anything else. From my 1st comment: "I did not talk about a specific implementation. About symbols with internal linkage: There is no need to do so. That might be a debugging aid, though."

Comment: @Olaf and it's irrelevant for a question asking "why is this happening?" C has implementation-defined aspects, and we're basically discussing ABIs now.

Comment: @FelixPalmen which are not part of  the C standard. Hence the C tag is not correct.

Comment: Please stop with the back-and-forth over the [c] tag. This isn't worth fighting over, and if you'd like to discuss whether it is or is not an appropriate tag, please take that to chat or to Meta.

Comment: @Davmac Wikipedia isn't talking about C++. Certainly here on Windows we make that distinction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It specifically lists examples for C and C++, and the C examples are specifically what OP is asking about, and are specifically referred to there as "name mangling". While wikipedia isn't really an authoritative source, my point is that if you want to claim OP's terminology is wrong you should do so with authority (or just accept that not everyone always uses the same words in the same way - wikipedia shows that _someone_ disagrees with you).

Answer (score 8):

This is not what's commonly called *name mangling*. Name mangling is for C++ to create distinguished symbol names from functions of the same name (and is unfortunately implementation defined). Here you have a simple ["decorated name"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx#FormatC) by the conventions of win32 ABI. Windows uses them to distiguish different calling conventions available on that platform.

In this case, the single `@` denotes the `stdcall` calling convention and the number following is the number of bytes in the argument list. The `WINAPI` macro expands to some compiler-specific attribute that selects `stdcall` as the calling convention.

Different ABIs use different name decorations. E.g. on Linux, your standard calling convention is `cdecl` and it doesn't use any decoration at all. But you could have decorations containing a *symbol version* (coincidentally after an `@` sign)

Comment: *"In this case, the single @ denotes the stdcall calling convention"* It is not only the @ that denotes the stdcall calling conventions (because the fastcall calling convention also uses the @). What denotes the stdcall calling convention is the leading underscore and the @ and the number after the @ which represents the number of bytes for the parameters.